# Print csv to console

Tags: python

I am reading in a csv file with ten lines to transfer to JSON, console output as below. Python code attached. First step is to print csv data to console and error below occurring.

Syntax errors were occurring but after fixing them this error has began.

```
data = {}
with open(csvFilePath) as csvFile:
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
    for csvRow in csvReader:
        hmid = csvRow["hmid"]
        data[hmid] = csvRow
```

Console output:

```
python csvjson.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "csvjson.py", line 12, in <module>
    hmid = csvRow["hmid"]
KeyError: 'hmid'
```

Expected Output:

Prints out the CSV data to conole.

Comment: The way csv.DictReader works, if you don't provide a fieldname parameter, it gets the field names from the first row of the csv file.  So it seems likely that the csv you are reading does not have "hmid" in its first row.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader

Comment: csv.DictReader will form an OrderedDict object where the keys are the first row if fieldnames are not supplied. We can't see what your keys are from this. What is the output if you print(csvRow)?

Comment: Your error look like you can't reach the "hmid" column for the row. The index of the dict are number not the column header name. Try to call csvRow[0] or index of the column. Don't forget that the first row will contain the headers

Comment: csv frist two line: 

hmid,first_name,last_name,email,gender,passport_number,departure_city,arrival_city,aircraft_type
1,Lotstring,Duobam,anatwick0@samsung.com,Female,7043833787,Changtang,Tours,B737

Comment: What is your desired output to the console and/or dictionary structure? It's possible that if you look at `csvRow` it is already as you desire, so no need to create the `data` dict.

Comment: Thank you for comments, I changed it to search for second in row and output works. It does not read the first parameter from the csv?

'{
    "David Cummings": {
        "\u00ef\u00bb\u00bfnumber": "10378957899",
        "firstname": "David Cummings",
        "lastname": "Vladimir",
        "passportnumber": "757037",
        "destination": "Tajikistan"'

Answer (score 0):

The [KeyError exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyError) means that the key you are requesting does not exist in that dictionary.

If that column "hmid" does not exist in every row of the csv, consider using the dict.get() method. This will return None if the key does not exist in the dictionary instead of the KeyError.

Alternatively you can catch that KeyError and skip the row. That would look something like this.

```
data = {}
with open(csvFilePath) as csvFile:
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
    for csvRow in csvReader:
        try:
            data[csvRow["hmid"]] = csvRow
        except KeyError:
            pass
```

Or check if the key is in the dictionary before proceeding.

```
data = {}
with open(csvFilePath) as csvFile:
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
    for csvRow in csvReader:
        if "hmid" not in csvRow.keys():
            continue
        data[csvRow["hmid"]] = csvRow
```

Comment: The csv first two lines are as follows:

hmid,first_name,last_name,email,gender,passport_number,departure_city,arrival_city,aircraft_type
1,Lotstring,Duobam,anatwick0@samsung.com,Female,7043833787,Changtang,Tours,B737

Answer (score 0):

I made the following file 'test.csv' :

```
hmid,first_name,last_name,email,gender,passport_number,departure_city,arrival_city,aircraft_type
1,Lotstring,Duobam,anatwick0@samsung.com,Female,7043833787,Changtang,Tours,B737
2,Rover,Red,rr@nowhere.com,Female,7043833787,Changtang,Tours,B737
```

pasted your code into Python 2.7, and it worked fine.  `data` has two rows.

Maybe your file had an issue with terminators.

Comment: Thank you for this, I have just checked my Python version: Python 3.7.3, could this be the issue?, why would this make a difference?

I made a change, i put hmid to the end of the string, calling it worked perfectly and the output seems to just not like the first input:

{
    "324987654": {
        "\u00ef\u00bb\u00bffirstnames": "David Cummings",
        "lastname": "Vladimir",
        "passportnumber": "757037",
        "destination": "Tajikistan",
        "id": "324987654"

Any idea on the "\u00ef\u00bb\u00bf" seems some sort of unicode error

Answer (score 0):

CSV files have a BOM (byte order mark) at the beginning of the file, so when you open the file you need to specify encoding='utf-8-sig' on the file open. Here is your code, corrected:

```
data = {}
with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8-sig') as csvFile:
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
    for csvRow in csvReader:
        hmid = csvRow["hmid"]
        data[hmid] = csvRow
```